# Display trip time in an ios app

Tags: ios, iphone, google-maps, ios7, apple-maps

I am trying to display the time it would take for a user to drive from his current location to a location input by the user. I have been looking at the google maps api as well as the apple maps api and cannot for the life of me find a way to do this simple task. If anyone has any insight as to how to do this I would be very grateful for some direction.

Answer (score 0):

If you were to use map kit you could use [MKRoute](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/MapKit/Reference/MKRoute_class/Reference/Reference.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40013265) expectedTravelTime.